Groups and Group totals in Paginated Report
I am working on a Paginated Report by using data source as Power BI dataset. I was trying to create group on below columns and add the totals to each group.

Vendor
CategoryCode
SubCategoryCode

Problems in current Report.

Totals is not correct
Groups is not properly coming.

My current Report:

If you see above image, grouping is not happening at category code and sub category code level and total of amount also wrong. I need below output.
Output I need:

I have added Parent Group as Vendor and added Child Group Category Code and another Child Group Sub Category Code. I have added a Group Total for each group.

It looks like the grouping is by Vendor for all three groups. The subtotals are showing the overall total and the text are showing the first record. Check the Group Expressions in the Group Properties (right click on the group row and Row Group -> Group Properties. The first should be Sub Cat. Then the 2nd group row should be Cat.
